# Broadcasting (N,2,2) array and (N,2) array through a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, broadcasting

I am trying to migrate some code from MATLAB to python and I am having trouble understanding why the following code does not work.

```
import numpy as np

ngrid = 56
A = np.random.randint(10, size =(ngrid*ngrid,2))
A_tmp = A
B = np.random.randint(10,size =(ngrid*ngrid,2,2) )


for jj in range(ngrid*ngrid):
    A[jj,:] = A_tmp[jj,:]*B[jj,:,:].conj()
```

When I execute this code I get the error.

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2,)
```

I am not understanding why this is giving me a one dimensional array vs a `(ngrid*ngrid,2)` array.

The MATLAB code I am trying to recreate for is

```
for jj = 1:ngrid^2
    Psi0(jj, :) = Psi0_tmp(jj, :)*dia2adi(:,:, jj)';
end
```

Any guidance on theory and how to correct my code would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: It's giving you a 1d array because slicing a 1d slice of a numpy array is a 1d array. Contrast this to MATLAB where 1d arrays don't exist: everything is at least 2d.

Comment: It's too late here for me to try and come up with an elegant (read: vectorized) solution, but at worst you can use something like `A = np.einsum('ja,jab -> jb', A_tmp, B.conj())` instead of the whole loop. Give or take a transpose which is implied by MATLAB's prime operator.

Comment: I have been hearing about this 'magical' einsum. Thanks for the help, problem solved.

Comment: I think you can't pull this off with matmul, so the only other option is `A = (A_tmp[..., None] * B.conj()).sum(1)`. It will probably be faster than einsum at the cost of more memory.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take this in to consideration when I am optimizing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In numpy, the multiplication symbol is always element-wise (like `.*` in Matlab). For matrix multiplication, use `@`.

Also, you can do exponentiation in Python with `**`.

Therefore, if you change the loop to the code below, it works.

```py
for jj in range(ngrid**2):
    A[jj,:] = A_tmp[jj,:] @ B[jj,:,:].conj()
```